# Find, split and concatenate

Tags: python, split, find, concatenation

I have to find certain supplier according number in the second line (17. position)

For example , I have to find , split and concatenate this type of text - 
(The specifier for find , split and concatenate is second line - NUMBER , which consists
from 6 numbers , so I have to find this number and concatenate according this number)

Do I have to use some kind of regular expressions ? or only find,split and concatenate ?
(according numbers - 45107, 57107)

Output is also here:

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

Output (after find , split and concatenate):

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

```
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

Comment: I don't see six numbers anywhere...

Comment: adding some expected output may make your question a little clearer

Comment: Hi ! numbers 47107 and 57107 , expected output is also here , plz help.

Comment: what does your input look like?

Comment: Now I don't see the difference between input and output. Maybe I need coffee...

Comment: I also need a coffee :) There are 5 parts and output consists from 5 parts also , but is a little different between output and input , I need numbers (47107 and 57107 NEXT to EACH OTHER :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the output sorted by the number so you can use `re.split` and sort with a `lambda` if all your output is as posted:

```
s = """
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
"""
import re

srt = sorted(re.split("(?<=which CPython is used.)\n",s),key=lambda x: re.findall("\d{5}",x))

for line in srt:
   print line

Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             47107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
Add and Remove Platforms.
             57107 Specify which Python runtime, CPython or Jython, to use as a
Choose which CPython is used.
```

Comment: how you find that this is the problem of OP?

Comment: @Kasra,  *I need numbers (47107 and 57107 NEXT to EACH OTHER)* which from the output looks very much like a sorted list of items, sorted by the 5 digit number